# Converting UTF8 to ANSI (ISO-8859-1) in Delphi

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-2010, ansistring

I have a question about a code that i have to convert UTF8 strings to ANSI strings. My code works for accents in vowels, but with letter Ñ it doesn't work. The code breaks the string. How can I fix this mistake?

The string I have in UTF8: EDIFICIO PEÃ‘AS BLANCAS 
The string I would have in ANSI if correct: EDIFICIO PEÑAS BLANCAS 
The string I have in ANSI now: EDIFICIO PE

The code is here:

```
    function TFormMain.convertir_utf8_ansi(const Source: string):string;
    var
       Iterator, SourceLength, FChar, NChar: Integer;
    begin
       Result := '';
       Iterator := 0;
       SourceLength := Length(Source);
       while Iterator < SourceLength do
       begin
          Inc(Iterator);
          FChar := Ord(Source[Iterator]);
          if FChar >= $80 then
          begin
             Inc(Iterator);
             if Iterator > SourceLength then break;
             FChar := FChar and $3F;
             if (FChar and $20) <> 0 then
             begin
                FChar := FChar and $1F;
                NChar := Ord(Source[Iterator]);
                if (NChar and $C0) <> $80 then break;
                FChar := (FChar shl 6) or (NChar and $3F);
                Inc(Iterator);
                if Iterator > SourceLength then break;
             end;
             NChar := Ord(Source[Iterator]);
             if (NChar and $C0) <> $80 then break;
             Result := Result + WideChar((FChar shl 6) or (NChar and $3F));
          end
          else
             Result := Result + WideChar(FChar);
       end;
    end;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What Delphi version? - the optimal solution depends on it. Add the appropriate tag.

Comment: The first string you have isn't being displayed as UTF-8. It's UTF-8-encoded bytes being *interpreted as* something else, probably ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252. If you had interpreted your UTF-8 bytes as UTF-8 in the first place, you likely wouldn't have this problem. What you should investigate is where `Source` came from and why it's wrong.

Comment: It sounds awfully like you've asked the wrong question and fallen in to the classic XY problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue invoking, apart from the function that i had, the internal function UTF8toAnsi. I'm working on Delphi 2010.

This way:
Utf8toAnsi(convertir_utf8_ansi(source));

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Delphi 2009 or higher, you should let the RTL do the conversion for you:

```
type
  Latin1String = type AnsiString(28591); // codepage 28591 = ISO-8859-1
var
  utf8: UTF8String;
  latin1: Latin1String;
begin
  utf8 := ...; // your source UTF-8 string
  latin1 := Latin1String(utf8);
end;
```

If you are using Delphi 2007 or earlier, you can still do the conversion, just let the OS do it for you:

```
var
  utf8: UTF8String;
  latin1: AnsiString;
  ws: WideString;
  len: Integer;
begin
  utf8 := ...; // your source UTF-8 string
  len := MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, PAnsiChar(utf8), Length(utf8), nil, 0);
  SetLength(ws, len);
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, PAnsiChar(utf8), Length(utf8), PWideChar(ws), len);
  len := WideCharToMultiByte(28591, 0, PWideChar(ws), Length(ws), nil, 0, nil, nil);
  SetLength(latin1, len);
  WideCharToMultiByte(28591, 0, PWideChar(ws), Length(ws), PAnsiChar(latin1), len, nil, nil);
end;
```