# Delphi - url encoded filename? Convert To Ansi

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-8, urlencode

I have spent most of the day looking for a solution but i can't figure it out, so i thought i'd ask the experts here.

In Outlook there is a mail message with attachments, some of the attachments have a filename with words like 'dossier pièces signée'.

We import the mail in the application but we noticed something strange with the filename of the attachment, the filename we save in the database does not match the actual filename.

After a long search i discovered the 'è' character is actually 2 characters and when i paste this in notepadd++ and show it as ansi i get 'pieÌ€ces' instead of 'pièces', so i think (but am unsure) this filename is a url encoded filename.

Since we don't do unicode or utf-8 in our database i think it would be best to store the filename after converting it to ansi, however i can't find any Delphi function that returns it like to the notepad++ format.

Does anyone have any advice please?

Comment: Doesn't sound like ANSI would be the answer to a problem of handling international text. Unicode really isn't that hard.

Answer (score 1):

In delphi 2010 and after there's a Utf82Ansi internal function.

See more details in that answer here in stackoverflow: [Converting UTF8 to ANSI (ISO-8859-1) in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33613521/10300)